# How to solve "Could not get unknown property 'uploadArchives' for task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer"?

Tags: android

org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'uploadArchives' for task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.

I'm tring to build old project but getting this error.